# Internet Explorer dropping the "v" in .gov email addresses in a PHP app

Tags: php, internet-explorer, email

We've built an online event registration application built in PHP. We've discovered a bug in which email addresses entered into the system (for auto-email reply, self-retrieving one's registration, etc) and the email addy is a .gov email address, **the "v" gets dropped**, therefore all emails generated from the system do not get sent to the proper recipient. We've done testing and this appears to only occur when the registrant uses Internet Explorer.

Comment: You'll need to post example code of how you're gathering the email address from the user.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without further details. Please provide further details such as code / debugging info.

Answer (score 3):

We fixed the bug and here is what we found:

> "It was javascript--client side
>   script. Every email address went
>   through a function called "trim()"
>   during the page data validation step.
>   Trim() was intended to strip
>   non-printing characters (spaces, tabs,
>   etc) that were leading or trailing the
>   address. The characters are identified
>   using a backslash notation: \t is tab
>   for example. There is another
>   non-printing character called a
>   Vertical Tab, which is (normally)
>   defined \v. But apparently a version
>   of IE released sometime in the last 15
>   months enterprets \v as "v" and it
>   stripped that character. The fix was
>   basically to gut my "trim()" function.
>   It now does nothing"

Though, we would like to know why IE's javascript engine stopped
interpreting \v as vertical space and started interpreting it as the
letter 'v'.